# Trying To Set a Nested Object - Getting "IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type"

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `Race` object which has a `randomArticlesPair` property. This property is initialised to be `null` . This is how this object's `document` looks like in the database:

[image]

I'd like to **`set`** the `randomArticlesPair` property ***later***  and put a ***`custom object`*** instead, and this is how I do it:

```
CollectionReference usersRef= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseConstants.USERS);
DocumentReference senderRef=usersRef.document(raceRoom.getSenderEmail()).collection(FirebaseConstants.RACES_FEED).document(raceRoomID);

Map<String,Object> randomArticlesPair=new HashMap<>();
randomArticlesPair.put(FirebaseConstants.RANDOM_ARTICLES_PAIR,raceRoom.getRandomArticlesPair());

senderRef.set(randomArticlesPair,SetOptions.merge());
```

---

This is the `RandomArticlePair` object that I'm trying to insert:

```
public class RandomArticlesPair {

    private RandomArticle randomArticleA;
    private  RandomArticle randomArticleB;

    public RandomArticlesPair(){}

    public RandomArticlesPair(RandomArticle randomArticleA, RandomArticle randomArticleB) {
        this.randomArticleA = randomArticleA;
        this.randomArticleB = randomArticleB;
    }

    public RandomArticle getRandomArticleA() {
        return randomArticleA;
    }

    public RandomArticle getRandomArticleB() {
        return randomArticleB;
    }
}
```

Its properties are two `RandomArticle` objects:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class RandomArticle {
    private String title, firstParagraph, id, url;
    @Exclude private List<Linkshere>backTemplates_List;
    @Exclude private List<Backlink>backlinks_List;

    public RandomArticle(){}

    public RandomArticle(String title, String firstParagraph, String id, String fullUrl){
        this.title=title;
        this.firstParagraph=firstParagraph;
        this.id=id;
        this.url=fullUrl;
    }

    public RandomArticle(String title, String fullUrl){
        this.title=title;
        this.url=fullUrl;
    }

    public RandomArticle(String title, String firstParagraph, String id, String fullUrl, List<Linkshere>backTemplates_List){
        this.title=title;
        this.firstParagraph=firstParagraph;
        this.id=id;
        this.url=fullUrl;
        this.backTemplates_List=backTemplates_List;

    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getFirstParagraph(){
        return this.firstParagraph;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getURL(){
        return this.url;
    }

    @Exclude public List<Linkshere> getBacktemplatesList(){
        return this.backTemplates_List;
    }

    @Exclude public void setBacklinks_List(List<Backlink> backlinks_List) {
        this.backlinks_List = backlinks_List;
    }

    @Exclude public List<Backlink> getBacklinksList(){
        return this.backlinks_List;
    }

}
```

---

**My problem** is that after trying to add the new data, I'm getting this error:

```
05-06 22:59:17.313 2991-2991/com... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com..., PID: 2991
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com....infrastructure.objects.random_article.RandomArticlesPair (found in field randomArticlesPair)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter$zza.zzb(SourceFile:232)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.zzb(SourceFile:578)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.zza(SourceFile:452)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.zza(SourceFile:479)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.zza(SourceFile:445)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseMergeData(SourceFile:275)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(SourceFile:149)
        at com....multiplayer.races.RaceActivity_Sender$6.onDataChange(RaceActivity_Sender.java:199)
        at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

---

Inserting a **string** works just fine:

```
randomArticlesPair.put(FirebaseConstants.RANDOM_ARTICLES_PAIR,"plain old string");
```

[image]

---

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "It happened with every object I've tried to set instead of this null value."

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited my question. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: What if you just try to put a plain old string?

Comment: what is that doc type?plus what you need to do is to update children not set value

Comment: @DougStevenson Inserting a string works just fine.

Comment: @D.'s What do you mean by doc type?

Comment: randomArticlesPair type?

Comment: There must be something invalid in the objects you're trying to add.  Please edit your question to be very specific about the object that that causes this error.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited my question. I'm now relating to the specific object in detail.

Comment: @D.'s Yes. It's a RandomArticlesPair.

Comment: Is there anything else in that error message: "Invalid data. Unsupported type"?  Like a java class or something?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the full error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the expectation is that you'd use POJOs or maps of primitive types, but not intermix them. In this particular case, since you already have a `Race` object, I think you could just write it directly, and then update it again later. Something like this:

```
Race race = createRaceObjectWithNullRandomArticlesPair();
senderRef.set(race);
...
race.setRandomArticlesPair(...);
senderRef.set(race, SetOptions.merge());
```

Would that work for your situation?

---

The difficulty in allowing maps of POJOs is that it isn't clear how they should be extracted, and we're trying to avoid an asymmetry between reads/writes, as we think it'll lead to more confusion in the long term.

For instance, you could pass in `Map.class` to the `DocumentSnapshot.toObject()` method, but due to java's type erasure, it would be difficult to specify that you want a map of strings to RandomArticlesPair objects. (Though it's not actually impossible. You could use an approach like the one described here: http://gafter.blogspot.ca/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html but that's getting a bit off-topic, since Firestore doesn't currently support anything like that.)

Comment: Your approach works for me. However, its downside is that it forces me to move around the "parent" object and not just its properties (the nested objects), which I already have in the current activity.

Comment: @TalBarda There is one other option, though I'm a little hesitant to point it out, as it's kinda kludgy and not supported. So I'll hide it down here in the comments. :)

You could cast your map to an Object. This will cause Firestore to treat the map itself, and everything inside it, as a POJO. i.e. instead of this:

    `senderRef.set(randomArticlesPair,SetOptions.merge());`

do this:

    `senderRef.set((Object)randomArticlesPair,SetOptions.merge());`

The difficulty is that it isn't possible to extract this in the same way, so this may lead to headaches down the road.